# Google Ads + iOS first_open conversion tracking issue

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-ads-api

I have a project on the Firebase, which contains both iOS and Android apps, which are tracking as expected in the Firebase and Analytics.

My next goal was to set up an ad campaign on the Google Ads website. I have linked both Firebase and Analytics accounts with my Google Ads account. Android is doing well and right after the linking conversions appeared and ad campaigns are running successfully. But with the iOS app I have problems - first_open conversion is not showing anywhere in the Google Ads console, and if I try to reimport conversions it shows, that I've already imported all of them. Because of that, I am not able to run iOS ad campaigns which are quite disappointing.

I saw a lot of requests like that on the web, but on all of them "Google GOLD Experts" are saying to recheck linking, which makes no sense.

Does anyone was able to fix this bug? I have found that MAYBE we should use Google Tag Manager and connect it with the Google Ads to track iOS conversations.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem with events coming from Firebase. The solution was to go to the iOS App in Firebase, then in settings add the App store ID.

To get the App store id go to the app in the app store, and it will be in the URL.

```
https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/APPNAME/id[The id is here]?mt=8
```

Comment: For those who did not publish their app yet, this is the same ID as here in App Store Connect: `https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/[The id is here]/appstore/...`

Comment: you are the best appreciate it

Comment: It's 2024 and this fix still works!

Comment: God save stackoverflow and all the people that create it's content. It would be just impossible to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if Sloth's answer helped but what worked for me was going to Tools & Setup > under Setup select Linked Accounts. Select "Manage & Link" next to Google Analytics, expand your project, and activate the iOS app.

Answer (score 3):

Good News!

I have had the exact problem and spent the whole week trying to figure this out.
Maybe this works for you as well.

I noticed that I had a third-party (Adjust) linked to my account.
I had unlinked it and the iOS conversion events started showing up all of a sudden.

My guess is that somehow Adjust was taking all the conversion events or something?

I don't really understand it but that's what did it for me, give it a try!

In Google Ads go to Settings> Linked Accounts> Details for ThirdPartyAnalytics and Unlink!

:)

Comment: I dont' have third party linked to my account but it still doesn't work. Do you have any idea to get the firebase export events to Google Ads?